# Microsoft Word 2007 responds slowly to keypresses, half second lag or more

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, keyboard, lag, delay

Pressing a key in MS Word results in **a delay before the screen updates**. This makes typing (whilst looking at the screen) a terrible experience. Documents are displayed as normal, and print as normal.

I have a clean Word 2007 installation on an Intel i5 2400, Windows 7 Pro. So it should perform decently, but it doesn't.

**The template I use is clean, save for an image in the page heading** that extends all the way to the bottom of the page.

What is causing this lag? There is no known macro virus or anything else going on. The CPU load is normal, very little software is installed and running on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: I **replaced the heading image with a small PNG image** and Word now works as normal.

I couldn't find good, relevant information for this issue, so I'm posting this here.

As it turns out, the large image in the heading, extending all the way to the bottom of the page, caused Word to be very slow.

Saving the word file produced a 1.1 MB file, which is large considering that it had barely any content besides the image and a few words of text. This is what prompted me to look at the heading.